# Symfony 2.2 form not binding request

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, formcollection

My controller code is

```
public function checkoutAction(Request $request) {
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form = $this->createForm(new RequestRunnerType() );
        $data = array();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $orderService = $this->container->get('order_service');
            $paymentMethod = $request->request->get('paymentMethod');
            if ($paymentMethod == 'requsetRunner') {
                $form->bind($request->request->get('requestRunner'));
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    //problem is here
                    $address = $form->getData();
                    $return = $orderService->createOrder($paymentMethod, $address['requestRunner']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Form class code is

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('id', 'hidden')
                ->add('buildingNo', 'text',array(
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
                ->add('floorNo', 'text',array(
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
                ->add('street', 'text',array(
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
                ->add('city', 'text')
                ->add('landmark', 'text',array(
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
                ->add('apartmentNo', 'text',array(
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('phoneNo', 'text')
                ->add('notes', 'textarea')
                ->add('currency', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'EGP' => 'EGP',
                        'USD' => 'USD'
                    ))
        );
    }
```

my Entity

```
<?php

namespace myapp\bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RequestRunner
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="request_runner")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RequestRunner
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderid;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phoneNo", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phoneno;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mobileNo", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $mobileno;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="notes", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $notes;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comments", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="weight", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $weight;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="appointment_from", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $appointmentFrom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="appointment_to", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $appointmentTo;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal", nullable=false)
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deliveryFees", type="decimal", nullable=false)
     */
    private $deliveryfees;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="employee", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $employee;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="courier", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $courier;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="waybill", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $waybill='';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlWaybill", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $urlwaybill;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rate", type="decimal", nullable=false)
     */
    private $rate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="currency", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deliveryTime", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $deliverytime=0;

    /**
     * @var string
     ***
     * @ORM\Column(name="chequeNo", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $chequeno=0;
}
```

My problem:**
When I bind request to form i get object full of NULLs
and when i print `$request->request->all();`
i get the values in post request as below

```
array (size=2)
  'paymentMethod' => string 'requsetRunner' (length=13)
  'requestRunner' => 
    array (size=12)
      'city' => string 'Cairo' (length=5)
      'buildingNo' => string '' (length=0)
      'street' => string '38 Hassnin Abdel Kader, Nasr City' (length=33)
      'apartmentNo' => string '' (length=0)
      'floorNo' => string '0' (length=1)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'phoneNo' => string '' (length=0)
      '_token' => string '1a8d21d49a5eb612a8b863b792b89b0ed0bb8b67' (length=40)
      'currency' => string 'EGP' (length=3)
      'landmark' => string 'Next to supermarket' (length=19)
      'notes' => string '' (length=0)
```

I tried to

```
$form->bind($request->request->get('requestRunner'));
```

and

```
$form->bind($request));
```

as Symfony 2.2 should is fetching the array and gets the form as documentation says but both are not working

Comment: Is this a typo or copy/paste issue: if ($paymentMethod == 'requsetRunner') {?

Comment: nop it's not it's another value in used in something else than form

Comment: did `isValid()` test pass?

Comment: I actually think I have the same problem. I am trying to bind data received from a request on a form builder and my entity comes back having only it's id.

Comment: @DonCallisto `isValid()` is `true`

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is the problem.

There is nothing to bind to the request.

I mean there is no `requestRunner` object to map to. You have two option, either in the form creation, you pass it or later with `$form->setData($requestRunner)`.

I doesn't tested it, but this should work:

```
public function checkoutAction(Request $request) {
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        $obj  = new RequestRunner();
        $form = $this->createForm(new RequestRunnerType(), $obj );
        $data = array();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $orderService = $this->container->get('order_service');
            $paymentMethod = $request->get('paymentMethod');
            if ($paymentMethod == 'requsetRunner') {
                $form->bind($request->get('requestRunner'));
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    //problem is here
                    //and here you can use the $obj variable what will be filled with the request data
                    $return = $orderService->createOrder($paymentMethod, $obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I got your code correctly, you wanted to pass to the createOrder function the whole requestRunner right?

I also changed some bits, you don't need the `getRequest()` cause you have that in the argument list of the function, and if you are extracting data from the request, you can use the get function on the request, or `$this->getRequest()->get('input name')`.

If doesn't work like this, then remove $obj from the createForm and befor `bind`, use the `$form->setData($obj)` functionality. ( Sorry don't remember which one is 2.2 and which one is the 2.3 way )

Comment: I figured it out it was my fault, i was binding wrong data from twig ,
thanks a lot for your efforts